# How in opentsdb do I add up all datapoints in a specified time range?

Tags: opentsdb

I'm using opentsdb.  I have ONE time series, with values at 10-minute intervals.   I want to specify a start time and an end time, and get back a single number that is the sum of all the values in the specified time range.  I tried what I thought to be correct

```
...start=<start>&end=<end>&m=sum...
```

but got back all the individual values rather than their sum.

Answer (score 0):

Add the element downsample="0all-sum"; apparently, the "0all" is interpreted as "the interval containing all timestamps".